# Angular 2 re-render UI with animation

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am stuck with a scenario, where there is a header that renders in the UI with animation. The value of header continuously changes with a subscription change every 2 seconds.

As the header is rendered, the animation is played once. But on each value change in the subscription, the animation is not played as the animation is already played once the DOM element was rendered. I am using animate.css here. How do I animate the header on each change of its value.

```
export class WebsiteContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  welcomeMessage: string;
  welcomeMessages: Array<string> = [];
  counter: number;
  sub: any;

  constructor() {
    this.welcomeMessages.push("नमस्ते");
    this.welcomeMessages.push("Welcome");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.welcomeMessage = "Welcome";
    this.sub = Observable.interval(5000).subscribe(val => {
      this.updateMessage();
    });
  }

  updateMessage() {
    if (this.counter + 1 === this.welcomeMessages.length) {
      this.counter = 0;
    } else {
      this.counter++;
    }
    this.welcomeMessage = this.welcomeMessages[this.counter];
  }
}

<h1 class="text-center heading-level-1 animated fadeIn">{{welcomeMessage}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular animations instead of simple css animations.

Here is a simple example for how you're doing this (the animation I've used in this example is just for example purpose, change it as needed):

Add `animations` decleration in your `@Component` decorator:

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
    trigger('welcomeAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [
        animate('1s', style({
          opacity: 0
        }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

Using the value `* => *` is responsible for the animation execute on each change to `welcomeMessage` variable.

Add this animation in your template like this:

```
<h1 [@welcomeAnimation]="welcomeMessage">{{welcomeMessage}}</h1>
```

> Checkout this [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animations-so54334048) to this in action